# MVC 5 TextboxFor with Bootstrap 3 icon not opening datepicker?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

In MVC 5 I'm trying to get jQUery UI datepicker to open up when you click on the Bootstrap icon.

I have this code that works but it does not link the add-on icon. It only links the textbox.

```
$(function () {
    $("#ReportRunDate").datepicker();
});

<div class="input-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReportRunDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I've found examples on making the add-on clickable but not with a TextboxFor, only with a input field. I also tried adding and id to the input-group div and calling that from JQuery but that didn't render out at all so it showed the textbox, calendar, and icon all stacked.

```
$(function () {
    $("#reportDatePicker").datepicker();
});

<div class="input-group datepicker" id="reportDatePicker">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReportRunDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

**UPDATE - Fixed**

```
    $(function () {
        $(".date-picker").datepicker();
    });

 <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="input-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReportRunDate, new { @class = "form-control date-picker" })
        <label for="ReportRunDate" class="input-group-addon btn">
            <span class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ReportRunDate, "", new { @class = "error-msg" })
</div>
```

Comment: Try example "B" here: http://jsfiddle.net/jasenhk/4g9u5/

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get it to work with that code. Funny thing is I had found one Jaasenhk had done before but it wasn't quite as extensive. That one worked as well but Add-On image was just slightly off from the input box (maybe 3px) and it made it look weird enough I didn't want to use it.